# Can't retrieve png file from drawable folder

Tags: eclipse

I can't retrieve my png file from the drawable folder with this code

```
RadioButton.OnClickListener myOptionOnClickListener = new RadioButton.OnClickListener(){

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    if (state.equals("second"))
    {
        if(list[0].isChecked())
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.d1);
        else
            image.setImageResource(-1);

        if(list[1].isChecked())
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.h7);
        else
            image.setImageResource(-1);
        }
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? Do you have the files `d1` and `h7` in the directory 'drawable'?

Comment: yes i have them in drawable-mdpi. im getting no error but i cant get the image when i hit the radiobutton

Comment: does that part of code (`image.setImageResource();`) get executed?

Comment: ya i think it is. I am not getting any error. can you suggest any other code?

Comment: try to call `image.setImageResource();` in your `onCreate()` method and see if it works.

Comment: no its not  working at  a;lll

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
image.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.d1));
```